# Alias in bashrc - can't get it to work

Tags: bash, alias

I created a shell script and wish to add it to bashrc. I opened /home/jub/bashrc and added the following to the end of the file:

`alias myfilesync = './/home/jub/Documents/scripts/myfilesync.sh'`

Then from terminal, executed:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Then I try to execute either

```
myfilesync
```

or

```
./myfilesync
```

Either way, the result is "No such file or directory".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the space before the equals sign a copy/paste typo or in the actual bashrc file? You'll also want to name the file .bashrc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided the script you just wrote is placed in your home directory, which I am assuming is, `/home/jub`, your `alias` directive should be

```
alias myfilesync='/home/jub/Documents/scripts/myfilesync.sh'
```

i.e., you need to drop the leading `./`

Comment: There also cannot be any spaces around the `=`.

Comment: It also might be worth while to explain why they need to drop the `./`

Comment: Thanks, dropped the `.\` and the spaces around the = sign, and it worked. How do I mark the question as answered?

Answer (score 1):

Just other answer

Open and edit your `.bashrc`

```
alias myfilesync='/home/jub/Documents/scripts/myfilesync.sh'
```

**Please note there are no spaces between `=`**

**Please note there's no leading `./`, while you are specifying the path of the script, it is not needed**

**Check the script has the execute permission**

Close your current terminal session and try again. If you want to skip this step, just set up the alias in your current prompt

```
$ alias myfilesync='/home/jub/Documents/scripts/myfilesync.sh'
```